# Почему не выводит тег label?

Tags: javascript

```js
var d = document.querySelector('table')
var s = document.querySelector('label')


for(var i = 0; i < d.children.length; i++){
  if(d.children[i] == s){
    console.log(d.children[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="search">
    <label>Поиск по сайту:
      <input type="text" name="search">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Искать!">
  </form>
  <hr>
<form name="search-person">
    Поиск по посетителям:
    <table id="age-table">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td>Возраст:</td>
        <td id="age-list">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="age" value="young">до 18
          </label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="age" value="mature">18-50
          </label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="age" value="senior">более 50
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: а вы посмотрите что у вас в `d.children` лежит и станет понятно почему не работает...

Comment: @InDevX а что делать если мне в переменной нужно именно table и и как вывести в консоль label ?

Comment: вам просто лейблы брать надо?

Comment: @InDevX да (какой-то текст)

Comment: Очередная школьная мего соц-сеть?) А вообще `document.querySelector('table label')` или проще раз нужны `lable` пачкой, юзать `querySelectorAll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var d = document.querySelector('table')
var s = d.querySelectorAll('label');

for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
  console.log(s[i]); // label
  console.log(s[i].textContent); //label text
}
```

```html
<form name="search">
    <label>Поиск по сайту:
      <input type="text" name="search">
    </label>
    <input type="submit" value="Искать!">
  </form>
  <hr>
<form name="search-person">
    Поиск по посетителям:
    <table id="age-table">
      <tbody><tr>
        <td>Возраст:</td>
        <td id="age-list">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="age" value="young">до 18
          </label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="age" value="mature">18-50
          </label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="age" value="senior">более 50
          </label>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```